# How to include a file from another (parent) directory

Tags: c, makefile, arduino-makefile

This is my structure

```
program/
  src/
    Makefile
    main.ino
    test.h
    ...
  lib/
    i2c.h
```

In `main.ino` I include `test.h` and in `test.h` I'm trying to include `i2c.h` but it is just not working, I keep getting:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'i2c.h', needed by 'build-uno/main.ino.o'.  Stop.
```

I tried including like this

```
// test.h
#include "../lib/i2c.h"
```

I also tried making a symlink to my lib folder in arduino libraries and adding it as a library in Makefile

`sudo ln -s /home/pi/program/lib /usr/share/arduino/libraries/GAVR`

```
# Makefile
ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino
BOARD_TAG = uno
ARDUINO_PORT = /dev/ttyAMA0
ARDUINO_LIBS = GAVR
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

I also tried making a symlink to lib inside the src directory

`ln -s /home/pi/program/lib /home/pi/program/src/lib`

None of the above had any effect, the error message stays the same.

How can I include a file from another directory in my program?

Comment: It's a make error not compilation error. If you have rule, for main.ino, where is that i2c.h listed as dependency and it's not in the same directory, it'll fail. Depends on Makefile directory it might be ../lib/i2c.h (or you can ommit this dependency, but if it changes, it won't get recompiled)

Comment: @KIIV I'm still quite new to c and I don't really know what I'm doing. My Makefile is in the `src` directory and I have posted the contents of it. I'm not aware how I must specify the `lib` directory as part of the build process. I found many examples that suggest adding `-I` to `gcc` but the arduino makefile does magic and I don't know how to add parameters to the compiler command.

Comment: I was using platformio (as there was no command line interface back then). 1. libraries are usually in it's own subdirectory, so it might need something like lib/i2c_lib/i2c.h and ARDUINO_LIBS=/home/pi/program/lib

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing with a Makefile (and Makefiles are black magic) then you really shouldn't be using one. If you must use the command line then use `ardiuno-cli` instead. Also be aware that building is not normally done in the source directory but in a separate build directory elsewhere.

Comment: @Majenko there are probably a lot of things I'm doing wrong, but all I care about is my program to work as I expect, everything else is noise. It's a hobby project on which I'm working alone so nobody is going to suffer from my ignorance and I'll likely never do any professional work with C, so it's fine. Guess I'll follow the advice if I can't figure out a way to make the Makefile work.

Comment: You may suffer the same problem with `arduino-cli` because of how Arduino building is done - not in the source directory. You will have to work out what the build directory's path is relative to where your file is. If you are using a proper library, though, then `arduino-cli` will know that and handle it all for you.

Comment: @Majenko I seem to have found a solution, following the symlink to `/usr/share/arduino/libraries/GAVR` I just had to create a `GAVR.h` file which includes my other files. That would probably make a proper C programmer cringe but it works for me, so I'm not sure whether I should put it as an answer or delete the question altogether.

Comment: Put it as an answer. It may help someone. And hey, if it works it works. In C there is more opinion than right and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely on the hacky side and not a proper solution to the problem, but it works nevertheless so I'm sharing it.

After making a symlink in the `/usr/share/arduino/libraries` directory you must make sure that there is a header file with the exact name of the directory, apparently that's how arduino is set up to include them.

In my case my symlink was named `GAVR`, so I had to create a `GAVR.h` file inside my `lib` directory, which would then go ahead and include my `i2c.h` file and possibly any other file that I'd need.

<strike>Also in `test.h` or anywhere I need to use `i2c.h` I must include `<GAVR.h>` instead.</strike>
Turns out Also 1 is false, you just need to include `<GAVR.h>` once in the `.ino` file and its members will be available everywhere, just like any other library.

Also 2, now that `ARDUINO_LIBS` is not empty in the `Makefile` you will need to manually declare *all* libraries that your code is using.